# gulp-rev-replace isn't changing the revisioned file names in my master.blade.php

Tags: node.js, gulp

I've been trying to create a build system using gulp in a Laravel project and the only problem left right now is renaming the right file names inside my `master.blade.php` file. As it is now, it's only following the filenames provided in the [**`gulp-useref`**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-useref) parameters, but the files revisioned by [**`gulp-rev`**](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-rev) are not replaced by [**`gulp-rev-replace`**](https://github.com/jamesknelson/gulp-rev-replace).

Here is my gulp task:

```
gulp.task('build', ['clean', 'scss', 'js', 'master'], function() {

    var assets,
        jsFilter        = $.filter('**/*.js'),
        cssFilter       = $.filter('**/*.css');

    return gulp.src('app/views/layouts/master.blade.php')
        .pipe(assets = $.useref.assets({searchPath: '/'}))

        .pipe(jsFilter)
        .pipe($.uglify())
        .pipe(jsFilter.restore())

        .pipe(cssFilter)
        .pipe($.csso())
        .pipe(cssFilter.restore())

        .pipe($.rev())
        .pipe(assets.restore())
        .pipe($.useref())
        .pipe($.revReplace())

        .pipe($.rename(function(path) {
            if(path.extname === '.php') {
                path.dirname = 'app/views/layouts';
            } else {
                path.dirname = 'public/assets';
            }
        }))

        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'))
        .pipe($.size({title: 'build files', showFiles: true}))

        .on('end', function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                // force watchify to close all watchers
                process.exit();
            });
        });

});
```

The default `master.blade.php` would look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{{$title}}</title>

    <!-- build:css assets/index.css -->
    <!-- bower:css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/components-font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" />
    <!-- endbower -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/.tmp/index.css">
    <!-- endbuild -->
</head>
<body>

    <section id="container">
        <header>
            @include('layouts.navbar')
        </header>
        <aside>
            @include('layouts.sidebar')
        </aside>
        <section>
            @yield('content')
        </section>
        <footer>
            @include('layouts.footer')
        </footer>
    </section>

    <!-- build:js assets/index.js -->
    <!-- bower:js -->
    <script src="/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/lodash/dist/lodash.compat.js"></script>
    <!-- endbower -->
    <script src="/.tmp/index.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->

</body>
</html>
```

and the result will always look like this despite the **`gulp-rev-replace`** pipe.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{{$title}}</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/index.css">
</head>
<body>

    <section id="container">
        <header>
            @include('layouts.navbar')
        </header>
        <aside>
            @include('layouts.sidebar')
        </aside>
        <section>
            @yield('content')
        </section>
        <footer>
            @include('layouts.footer')
        </footer>
    </section>

    <script src="assets/index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out the problem, The `gulp-rev-replace` documentation mentions that they only replace files with extensions `['.js', '.css', '.html', '.hbs']` by default. By passing ['.php'] in the [**`replaceInExtensions`**](https://github.com/jamesknelson/gulp-rev-replace#user-content-optionsreplaceinextensions) option.

Comment: I have the same problem with my gulp/laravel5 setup. Adding `".php"` didn't fix my problem. Instead of `".php"` adding `".blade"` solves everything. You can consider this when you exprienced same issue.